# How i get real baner image size in open cart banner module?

Tags: opencart

I am trying to get real image size(s) of banner images in open cart banner module.

Actually, It is converting to sizes given in admin but i want to get all real dimensions.

> For example, 300 x 250 and 300 x 600

Is there any way i can get these images in its real sizes?

Comment: Well if you want to completely remove the resize in banners, you have to edit the banner.php in catalog/controller/module folder. Please specify your case a bit more clearly, do you want to generally remove the resize in banners or not?

Comment: How i remove it. Please can you show me some code example?

Answer (score 0):

Remove image resize from banner:

1. go to **catalog\controller\module**
2. edit banner.php
3. find this line

   `'image' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $setting['width'], $setting['height'])`
4. replace with `'image' => DIR_IMAGE.$result['image']`

and you are done.

Comment: just edited the question, i forgot to add the part that call the image directory, sorry for that :)